# Single space being added in download

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter based website running and am wanting users to download a .ics file. On the server, there is no leading space in the file. When a  user downloads the file, there is a leading space.

This has naturally confused me. I would do a `die();` to see what is going on, but I am not sure where to even start.

**Routes**

```
$route['ics/'] = 'ics';
```

**Controller**

```
        $ics_token = $this ->uri->segment(2);

        // Directory path containing the calendar exports
        $core_directory    = $COMP_config->writable .'/calendar/';

        $ics_file = FALSE;

        if($this->uri->segment(2) == 'calendar.ics'){

            $ics_file = $core_directory . 'calendar.ics';

            $ics = file_get_contents($ics_file);

            header('Content-type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');
            header('Content-Disposition: inline');

            // new line feeds NEED to be a real new line!
            $ics = str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $ics);
            die(trim($ics));

        }
```

***View***

```
$ics_url = site_url().'ics/calendar.ics';
<p class="text-center">Enter this URL into iCal, Google Calendar, Outlook: <a href="<?php echo $ics_url; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo($ics_url); ?></a></p>
```

I am at a loss as to where I should be looking to do some debugging.

Comment: You're missing the closing `'` in the first row in your view.

Comment: Maybe the space comes from some part outside the `<?php ... ?>` block.

Comment: Make sure that you have no leading space before your `<?php`-tag.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - there was a leading space in the controller file, removed that but still happening. On the server there is no space, but when i download the file via the view, there is a leading space. So something in the view?

Comment: @karliwson - Where about are you thinking? Any thoughts on what could cause it?

Comment: @PierreOdendaal the same thing Magnus said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your help. Turns out there was a space before the opening of `<?php` in a couple of files that generated the page that the link was on.